# passing arguments to functions in php

Tags: php, arrays, function, arguments, argument-passing

I have some php code that is pretty much being duplicated save for some minor variable naming differences. How can I turn this into a reusable function where I can pass arguments thru?

This is the code which I am using twice. The second one is the same except all references of "affiliate" is changed to "social".

```
<?php
    $affiliate = wp_list_bookmarks( array( 'categorize' => 0, 'category' => '7', 'title_li' => '', 'orderby' => 'rating', 'show_images' => 0, 'echo' => 0 ) );
    preg_match_all( '/<li>.*?<\/li>/', $affiliate, $affiliate_matches );
    foreach ( $affiliate_matches[0] as $affiliate_match ) {
        preg_match( '/title=".*?"/', $affiliate_match, $affiliate_title );
        echo str_replace(
            $affiliate_title[0],
            $affiliate_title[0] . ' ' . strtolower( str_replace( array( 'title="', ' ' ), array( 'class="', '-' ), $affiliate_title[0] ) ),
            $affiliate_match
        ) . "\n";
    }
?>
```

The other one is:

```
<?php
    $social = wp_list_bookmarks( array( 'categorize' => 0, 'category' => '2', 'title_li' => '', 'orderby' => 'rating', 'show_images' => 0, 'echo' => 0 ) );
    preg_match_all( '/<li>.*?<\/li>/', $social, $social_matches );
    foreach ( $social_matches[0] as $social_match ) {
        preg_match( '/title=".*?"/', $social_match, $social_title );
        echo str_replace(
            $social_title[0],
            $social_title[0] . ' ' . strtolower( str_replace( array( 'title="', ' ' ), array( 'class="', '-' ), $social_title[0] ) ),
            $social_match
        ) . "\n";
    }
?>
```

I was thinking maybe I can call the function like

`<?php links( array( 'affiliate', 7 ) ); ?>`

or

`<?php links( array( 'social', 2 ) ); ?>`

---

Would combining them into a reusable function save processing time/resources or would it not matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing that really changes is the category id so you only need to pass this to the function.

```
function links($categoryId) {
        $affiliate = wp_list_bookmarks( array( 'categorize' => 0, 'category' => $categoryId, 'title_li' => '', 'orderby' => 'rating', 'show_images' => 0, 'echo' => 0 ) );
        preg_match_all( '/<li>.*?<\/li>/', $affiliate, $affiliate_matches );
        foreach ( $affiliate_matches[0] as $affiliate_match ) {
            preg_match( '/title=".*?"/', $affiliate_match, $affiliate_title );
            echo str_replace(
                $affiliate_title[0],
                $affiliate_title[0] . ' ' . strtolower( str_replace( array( 'title="', ' ' ), array( 'class="', '-' ), $affiliate_title[0] ) ),
                $affiliate_match
            ) . "\n";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Heh.. stupid me. I overlooked that point. I guess it's time to sleep. Too bad I can't delete the post now.

Answer (score 0):

It would not save any computer time, what it saves is your time, by not having to maintain code twice. (But watch out that converting it into a function does not cause you to spend more effort than just having it twice.)

Also, I see no reason to pass the word 'social' to the function - it's never actually used anywhere.